# How do i stop Vscode from truncating output of python dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

I've tried to mention pandas setting and set **display width** to no avail. I just want vscode to show me the full output. Some other posts said there was a **setting called 'Data Science'**. I could not find that anywhere in vscode.

This was a .py file it was running some other code which contain s3 bucket URLs which is why I refrained from showing the original code.

Nevertheless I can emulate the same in this simpler code snippet on another file which creates a dataframe as so.

```
import pandas as pd

df_col1 = [12132432432423432,32423432432534523,34354354353454333,44353453453453454,53454353453453453]
df_col2 = ['test_url_thats_too_big_to_display_here' + str(i) for I in df_col1]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(df_col1, df_col2)), columns = ['a', 'b'])

print(df)
```

The above code creates 2 columns one with an id number and the other with an id appended with the URL. Below is the output of the code.

[image: Original Code Output]

Comment: Try print(df.to_string())

Comment: Please refer to this note before you complete your questions  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/data-science-tutorial#_prerequisites

Comment: @rioV8 Its a simple pandas dataframe with 3 columns, out of which I print 1. I did not show the code because the code consisted amazon s3 bucket URLs originally and I had modified the content to "test_url_thats_too_big_to_display_here". I think that its pretty trivial to infer that is a dataframe with a single column at least from the description, neverthe less. I'll add it.

Comment: @roganjosh refer above comment

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT I have installed all recommended python extensions, including the ones you mention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason to make data casting or novel series conversions. You can change pandas' configurations.

Check the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html#pandas-set-option).

Here a solution:

```
pd.get_option("display.max_colwidth")  # this is for your info only
50

pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", None)  # after this you can print any column length

# try it out:
s = pd.Series([["a" * 150]])
s
```

Comment: this is a better solution marking this as the answer

Comment: @GauravHazra If you liked it go ahead and upvote :)

Comment: Done. Appreciate the help kind sir.

Answer (score 1):

As per @wwii 's suggestion. using

```
print(df.to_string())
```

works perfectly

Here is a sample output of the code with last line change to the above

[image: Output of changed print method]

**Please use the solution suggested above by deponovo. It is more standard.**